# Почему возникает ошибка в динамическом массиве?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Есть динамический массив строк sample и целое число num. Что не так в этом коде:

```
sample[num] := 'blah blah blah';  
num := num + 1;  
setLength(sample, num);
```

Вылетает с "external: SIGSEGV"?!

Comment: Не ясно. У меня ваш пример выполняется и ничего не падает..

Comment: Что у вас за компилятор? Я собирал freepascal-ем

Comment: У меня lazarus.

Answer (score 2):

Если отключена проверка на границы массива, то пропустив инициализацию num можно в итоге получить такую ошибку. 
Добавление в конец лучше произвести

```
if length(sample)>0 then
sample[length(sample)-1]:='Что-то строчное';
setlength(sample,length(sample)+1);
```

Но правильнее сначала выделить память перед операцией и присвоить:

```
setlength(sample,length(sample)+1);
sample[length(sample)-1]:='Что-то строчное';
```

length() - функция asm, поэтому много времени не требует.

Answer (score 1):

По вашему вопросу есть обширное обсуждение:
[Error: Project raised exception class 'External:SIGSEGV'](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,6225.0.html).

Похоже, там есть кое-какие решения.

Comment: Там о вендузятниках. У меня линукс и я это читал.

Comment: @hamstertamer: Вы думаете, ошибка в программе на линуксе чем-то принципиально отличается от таковой под форточками?

Answer (score 1):

```
sample[num - 1] := 'blah blah blah';  
num := num + 1;  
setLength(sample, num);
```

или

```
sample[num] := 'blah blah blah';  
num := num + 1;  
setLength(sample, num + 1);
```

так как массив начинается с нуля